# Does Maven offer hooks at the very beginning of runtime

Tags: java, maven

Say we are running `mvn test`.

I am wondering if there is a way to configure Maven to run some files before executing tests. In my case, I want to configure a library, but don't want to have to configure this library for every entrypoint in my app/tests. I am just looking to configure the lib for every mvn lifecycle hook which invokes a runtime.

Something like this:

```
@MavenRuntimeLifecycle   
public class Whatever {

  public void runtimeBegin(){
      // right when the java process starts up
      Mylib.configure("foo");
  }

  public void runtimeEnd(){
     // right before the process shuts down
  }

}
```

I assume this would be a Maven specific thing - not that it has to be in the same Java process as my server or tests etc.

Note that using Node.js, I would simply do it like so:

```
export class MyLib {

  isConfigLoaded = false;

  static loadConfig(){
    // ...
  }

  static void run(){
    if(!this.isConfigLoaded){
      MyLib.loadConfig(require('../some/path/to/.mylib.config.js'));
      this.isConfigLoaded = true;
    }
    this.doTheThing();
  }

}
```

I could do the same thing with Java or Maven project, and just store a .java file in the resources directory.  It's more manual, but it could be done.

Comment: Could you say in more detail what you want to achieve, "configuring a library"?

Comment: @JFMeier a simple example would be a library that needs extra information (like loading a peer dependency) before it can run. It needs to be linked with that peer dependency before it can do anything. And the idea here is that one config file to setup the peer dependency will suffice for any entrypoint to the application and its tests.

Comment: What do you mean?